# JS innerHTML on <tag/> vs <tag></tag>

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <b /> <br>
      Lets say it again: <b /> <br>
    </body>

    <script>
       // this runs after document has already been loaded
       if (document.getElementsByTagName('b').length > 0) {
          Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('b')).forEach((ele) => {
              ele.innerHTML = "hello world!";
          });
       }
    <script>
</html>
```

The result is that only the first `<b />` gets its innerHTML modified. and NOTHING bellow this gets shown. Inspect shows no further HTML bellow the first `<b />`

However, if I replace `<b />` with `<b></b>` then everything works just fine.

Any idea why or how it could be fixed? I am using a tag to place a variable and I'd rather it be short as I have quite a few of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). The DOM you end up with when a browser attempts to parse that collection of errors is nothing like what you seem to be expecting, which is why the behaviour of the code isn't how you want.

Comment: TL;DR (but the answer that's linked is really good, do read it): `<b />` is not `<b></b>` in HTML, `<b/>` is just like `<b>` (due to error recovery in the parser). If you want `<b></b>`, write `<b></b>`. (HTML is not the same as JSX or XHTML.) Side note: `script` elements aren't allowed as direct children of `html` elements. They have to be in `head` or `body`.

Comment: @Quentin - FWIW, "that collection of errors" reads a bit harsh from a stranger on the 'net. :-) **I** know and you know that you don't mean it unkindly, but...

Comment: Thanks all. And Quentin - all taken with a smile :-)